# Transform JSON object keys to lowercase

Tags: javascript

So i have the following JSON object:

```
var myObj = {
   Name: "Paul",
   Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}
```

and I want to convert its keys to lowercase such that i would get:

```
var newObj = {
   name: "Paul",
   address: "27 Light Avenue"
}
```

I tried the following:

```
var newObj = mapLower(myObj, function(field) {
    return field.toLowerCase();
})

function mapLower(obj, mapFunc) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result,key) {
         result[key] = mapFunc(obj[key])
         return result;
    }, {})
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: field.toLowerCase is not a function".

Comment: There is a library called `humps` (https://github.com/domchristie/humps) which will handle several key transformations if you're trying to get to and from camelCase or PascalCase.  If you know your keys are always 1 word, then you probably don't need it but if you had keys like "first_name" or "FirstName" or "firstName", `humps` can normalize all those to the same shape.

Answer (score 6):

I'm really not sure what you were trying to do there with your `mapLower` function but you only appear to be passing in one argument which is the object value.

Try something like this (not recursive)

```js
var myObj = {
   Name: "Paul",
   Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}

const t1 = performance.now()

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObj).map(([ key, val ]) =>
  [ key.toLowerCase(), val ]))

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(newObj)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

This takes all the object entries (an array of key / value pairs) and maps them to a new array with the keys lowercased before creating a new object from those mapped entries.

---

If you need this to handle nested objects, you'll want to use a recursive version

```js
var myObj = {
  Name: "Paul",
  Address: {
    Street: "27 Light Avenue"
  }
}

// Helper function for detection objects
const isObject = obj => 
  Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Object]"

// The entry point for recursion, iterates and maps object properties
const lowerCaseObjectKeys = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(objectKeyMapper))
  
// Converts keys to lowercase, detects object values
// and sends them off for further conversion
const objectKeyMapper = ([ key, val ]) =>
  ([
    key.toLowerCase(), 
    isObject(val)
      ? lowerCaseObjectKeys(val)
      : val
  ])

const t1 = performance.now()

const newObj = lowerCaseObjectKeys(myObj)

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(newObj)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem :

```js
var myObj = {
   Name: "Paul",
   Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}

let result = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((prev, current) => 
({ ...prev, [current.toLowerCase()]: myObj[current]}), {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This answer is the worst, its complexity make it unusable with big objects.
My benchmarks with 1000 properties:
laguf1.mobi's operation took 35 ms, Ami Hollander's operation took 44 ms, Phil's operation took 131 ms, @tsamridh86's operation took 11838 ms

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myObj = {
   Name: "Paul",
   Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}

Object.keys(myObj).map(key => {
  if(key.toLowerCase() != key){
    myObj[key.toLowerCase()] = myObj[key];
    delete myObj[key];
  }
});

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: The fastest I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, but if you want to lower the key than you should do:

```js
var myObj = {
  Name: "Paul",
  Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}

function mapLower(obj, mapFunc) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, key) {
    result[mapFunc(key)] = obj[key]
    return result;
  }, {})
}

var newObj = mapLower(myObj, function(field) {
  return field.toLowerCase();
})

console.log(newObj)
```

will result with `{ name: 'Paul', address: '27 Light Avenue' }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `json-case-convertor`

```
const jcc = require('json-case-convertor')
var myObj = {
   Name: "Paul",
   Address: "27 Light Avenue"
}
const lowerCase = jcc.lowerCaseKeys(myObj)
```

Link to package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-case-convertor